# Triple integral, how to convert to spherical coordinates for $x^2+y^2+z^2\le x$

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

$$\iiint_\Omega{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz}$$
where $\Omega=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le x\}$.

I've only found answers for $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, and I don't know how to proceed - I believe I need to convert to spherical coordinates to solve the integral but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Hint: $$\rho^2\le\rho\cos\phi\cos\theta$$but you can use the axis differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by switching $x$ and $z$ we have that
$$I:=\iiint_\Omega{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz}=\iiint_{\Omega'}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz}$$
where $\Omega'=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le z\}=\{x^2+y^2+(z-1/2)^2\le 1/2^2\}$.

$\Omega'$ of is the ball with center $(0,0,1/2)$ and radius $1/2$.
It is entirely in the half-space $z \ge 0$. Therefore, in spherical coordinates, $\phi \in [0,\pi/2]$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$  and
$$\rho^2\leq z = \rho \cos{\phi} \implies \rho\leq \cos{\phi}.$$
Hence
$$I=\int_{0\phi=}^{\pi/2} \int_{\rho=0}^{\cos{\phi}}\int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi}\rho\cdot (\rho^2\sin{\phi})\ d\theta d\rho d\phi 
\\=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin{\phi}d\phi \: \int_0^{\cos{\phi}} \rho^3  d\rho\: \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta=\frac{\pi}{10}.$$

Comment: Just the teacher's notation for the domain (I'm from Romania so my terminology might be wrong sometimes)

Comment: @Alex E I mean what is $\Omega$ geometrically...

Comment: It is some sort of sphere, I just don't know how to deal with that $\le x$ . I'm sorry if i'm wrong somewhere

Comment: @AlexE. Robert is giving a hint by rewriting the inequality.  Do you recognize what set of points the second inequality $(x-1/2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1/2^2$ describes?

Comment: @Alex E. Sorry for the delayed answer, but I had to answer the phone...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it clicked after a while that it's just a different formula for a sphere and I could see it that way.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\Omega \equiv \braces{\pars{x,y,z}\ \mid\ x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} \leq x}}$.
>   Since there is a '*symmetry*' which involves the $\ds{y}$ and $\ds{z}$ variables, it's convenient to use *Cylindrical Coordinates* which are defined by:
>   $$
> \left.\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{x} & \ds{=} & \ds{x}
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{y} & \ds{=} & \ds{\rho\cos\pars{\phi}}
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{z} & \ds{=} & \ds{\rho\sin\pars{\phi}}
> \end{array}\right\}\,,\qquad
> x \in \mathbb{R}\,,\qquad \rho > 0\,,\quad \phi \in \pars{0,2\pi}
> $$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\iiint_\Omega\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z} =
\left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\root{\rho^{2} + x^{2}}\,\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ x^{2}\,\, +\, \rho^{2}\,\, \leq\,\, x}
\\[5mm] = &
\left. 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\root{\rho^{2} + x^{2}}\,\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ x^{2}\,\, +\ \rho^{2}\,\, \leq\,\, x}\,\, =
\left.\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,\int_{0}^{\infty}
\!\!\!\root{\rho + x^{2}}\,\dd\rho\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{\ \rho\ \leq\,\, x\ -\ x^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x - x^{2}}\root{\rho + x^{2}}\,\dd\rho\,\dd x
\quad\
\pars{~\mbox{because}\ \rho > 0\ \imp\ x - x^{2} > 0\ \imp\ x \in \pars{0,1}~}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left.{2 \over 3}\pars{\rho + x^{2}}^{3/2}
\,\,\right\vert_{\ \rho\ =\ 0}^{\ \rho\ =\ x - x^{2}}\,\,\,\,\dd x =
{2\pi \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{3/2} - x^{3}}\,\dd x =
{2\pi \over 3}\pars{{2 \over 5} - {1 \over 4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{\pi \over 10} \approx 0.3142
\end{align}